# HTML Button in the page

Tags: javascript, html

https://prnt.sc/wa75za

How can i add ***Continue*** in the string in text property where i also have href attribute to be added as well.

```
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            url: 'api/generate.php?type=links',
            success: function(data) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Here is your account',
                    text: '<a href="' + data +'">Continue</a>'
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try `html: '<a href="' + data + '">Continue</a>'`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:

> https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples

use **'html'** insetad of **'text'**

```
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            url: 'api/generate.php?type=links',
            success: function(data) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Here is your account',
                    html: '<a href="' + data +'">Continue</a>'
                });
            }
        });
```

CodePen Link:

> https://codepen.io/pen/